# 500 when trying to create order on the backend

Tags: admin, orders, admin-order-create

When I try to create an order from the admin and want to move from the cart on the left under Customer's Current Activities to the Items Ordered box on the top right side of screen i am getting the following message in the console
`https://example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/loadBlock/block/sidebar,items,shipping_method,billing_method,totals,giftmessage?isAjax=true 500 (Internal Server Error)` this only seems to be a problem some of the time but I do not have a clear pattern any one have an idea how i can uncover the problem? thanks

Comment: what exactly you see in error log?

Comment: nothing in the error log

Comment: this is something with php error so you need to check all logs you have

Comment: .htaccess related?

Comment: Were you able to resolve? I am having this error on 1.9.3.1

Comment: no i never resolved this